# Eclipse v3.7.1 on OS X: Wacky compiling errors

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion, nachos

I'm trying to compile Nachos OS in eclipse.  The project compiles fine when I run "make" (which calls javac), but when I try to run it in eclipse, it spits out some bizarre java errors.  For example, it is reporting that the last line of this javadoc comment is a file that it is unable to find...

Code Fragment:

```
/**
 * The master class of the simulated machine. Processes command line arguments,
 * constructs all simulated hardware devices, and starts the grader.
 */
public final class Machine {
    /**
     * Nachos main entry point.
     *
     * @param   args    the command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.print("nachos 5.0j initializing...");
```

Error Output:

```
/Users/dan/git/nachos/machine/Machine.java: line 19: */: No such file or directory
/Users/dan/git/nachos/machine/Machine.java: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/dan/git/nachos/machine/Machine.java: line 20: `    public static void main(final String[] args) {'
```

I am using OS X 10.7.2 (Lion) with Java SE 6 (1.6.0 jdk).
I have configured the build settings to use Nachos' Machine.Machine.java main function.

Any idea why the odd output from Eclipse?

Comment: How do you compile under Eclipse? I suppose you have "just" imported the Java files as a Java project in Eclipse?

Comment: I mean build and run I guess. I figure there's some compiling going on in there somewhere.

Comment: Eclipse will automatically build your Java project. But not with any error messages like these... So, I guess you are still running your make or...?

Comment: How do you get from "sources on web server" to "Eclipse project with said sources"?  Please retrace your steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the project file got corrupted in the process of loading it onto a bitbucket server.  I dropped eclipse like a bad habit in favor of IntelliJ.  Soooo much happier now.